# How to display PDF file on HTML without the grey taskbar?

Tags: javascript, css, html, pdf

I'm trying to do a gallery of pdf files on full-screen, is it possible to display them without this grey bar?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<embed src="http://URL_TO_PDF.com/pdf.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="425" height="425">
```

You just have to add few parameteres to the `src` attribute.

Here is the complete [list of parameters](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) that can be used

Answer (score 1):

Am sorry. This toolbar is  built-in for Google Chrome, so you won't be able to disable it for other visitors.

[Here is additional info about it.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1060734?hl=en)

I am supposed to comment this, but due to my lack of reputation points i posted the answer.